# html elements are picking click events outside their bounds

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, bounds

I have this code on my page

```html
    <div style="padding: 35px; background-color: red;" onclick="return false;">
            <img src="../assets/pictures/pic1.jpg" class="card" id="target" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" onclick="console.log('image clicked');">
</div>
```

It renders pretty well with the image shrunk inside the div and the div's red color showing where where it is not covered by the image.
The Problem is that when I click on the div which is shown by the red background color, the onclick event handler for the image still gets executed.

This happens until I click really far away from the boundary of the image.
What could be the cause?

EDIT: This happens when I turn the web page to mobile view to see how it would respond on various devices.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I can't recreate this using your exact code in any browser.

Comment: Your code works fine here, inside a code snippet.

Comment: I'm using opera brower.

Comment: Chrome is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I put the code in a codepen and the click even is only fired when I click inside the image, if I click outside the image, but still in the red background area the event doesn't happen(no console log). Because your click event is on the image, it only executes when you click on the image. Try a different browser for compatibility, I recommend Chrome or FireFox for their dev tools.

```
<div style="padding: 35px; background-color: red;" onclick="console.log('div clicked')">
        <img src="../assets/pictures/pic1.jpg" class="card" id="target" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" onclick="console.log('image clicked');">
```

The above code logs('Div Clicked') anytime you click inside the div, including on the picture. It also logs ('Image Clicked') if you click only on the image. So if you click outside the picture on the red, it will say "Div Clicked". If you click on the image, it was say "Div Clicked" "Image Clicked".

TL;DR : It seems to be working correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet works fine under (chrome, firefox, edge), can you precise which browser you are using, it can be a browser specific behaviour and the only little mistake in your code is that the img tag is not closed properly not sure if it can trigger such bug.

Comment: I forgot to add. This happens when I turn the web page to mobile view to see how it responds on various devices.

Answer (score 0):

I put the site on a live server and tested on a real mobile device, works very well as espected.
I think the problem lies in how browsers simulate mobile devices and their touch events.